# Oracle SQL Developer usage tracking over Windows Terminal Server (wts)

Tags: windows-terminal-services, sqldeveloper

The Oracle SQL Developer contains a usage tracking module. When you start the application the first time, it asks you whether you want to sent statistics to oracle or not. In a Windows Terminal Server hosted app I don't let the customers decide to sent or not. I found out, that the preference could be preset by a flag in the user home.

File: `%APPDATA%\SQL Developer\system<app version>\o.sqldeveloper\product-preferences.xml`

```
<hash n="oracle.ideimpl.usages.UsagesPrefs">
    <value n="track-usages" v="false"/>
</hash>
```

My question: Is there an easier way to enforce that flag, instead of having a script around the application, that checks the existence of the preferences file and modifies the flag if necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

I found some config in `../sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/ide/sqldeveloper.conf`:

`AddVMOption  -Dide.update.usage.servers=`

If you set this to some nonexistent website, the tracking stats won't get to Oracle (which is what you want, i presume).

`AddVMOption  -Dide.update.usage.servers=http://whateversomewebsiteitdoesntmatter.com:12345`

There could/should be some flag to unset the checkmark for allow-usage-tracking, maybe.

---

You can set the preferences system-wide if you configure the environment variable `IDE_USER_DIR` on the system.

Per default, all user-settings are stored in `%APPDATA%`.

See the corresponding files and settings [in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35137_01/appdev.32/e35117/intro.htm#RPTUG11200):

> The user-related information is stored in or under the IDE_USER_DIR
>   environment variable location, if defined; otherwise as indicated in
>   the following table, which shows the typical default locations (under
>   a directory or in a file) for specific types of resources on different
>   operating systems. (Note the period in the name of any directory named
>   .sqldeveloper.)

Comment: I think this also prevents the option for customizing the IDE by the user (connections, open views, filters, ..). I wouldn't do that.

Comment: Yes. But it's your only chance, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Nachtgold check my edit, maybe you can use that or derive something of it.

Comment: Ohh, good idea. I will sniff the traffic with that option.